# How to FLATTEN a test statement in Pig?

Tags: foreach, apache-pig, flatten

Using Pig .12.

I want to use a FOREACH with a block statement; the result, via GENERATE depends on some value. I know that i can use Flatten with a statement in it. I.e.:

```
grunt> d = foreach j2 { 
       ord = order j1 by A::a1 desc; 
       l = limit ord 1; 
       generate flatten((IsEmpty(l)?'f':'g')); };
```

This works.

But what i want to do:

```
grunt> d = foreach j2 { 
  ord = order j1 by A::a1 desc; 
  l = limit ord 1; 
  generate flatten((l.$0=='2') ?'f':'g'); };
```

> 2014-05-07 22:28:08,750 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt
>   - ERROR 1200:   mismatched input '?' **expecting RIGHT_PAREN**

Why does it say this?

I tried:

```
grunt> d = foreach j2 { 
ord = order j1 by A::a1 desc; 
l = limit ord 1; 
generate flatten(((l.$0=='2') ?'f':'g')); };
```

> 2014-05-07 22:40:44,895 [main] ERROR
>   org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1039:
>        (Name: Equal Type: null Uid: null)**incompatible types in Equal Operator left hand side:bag :tuple(A::a1:chararray)  right hand side:chararray**

And i dont know how to resolve this.

I just want to generate my results in a test case, but first need to flatten the test condition. 
Help ?
thanks,
Matt

Comment: Try using nested FOR LOOP statement, something like below
`foreach l { tmp = ((l.$0=='2') ?'f':'g'); generate flatten(tmp); }`

flatten expects a relation and what you are passing is an expression.